# I am constantly getting SSL error in Here Maps

Tags: android, ssl, here-api

Using Android 8.0 and 9.0 - I downloaded the HERE Maps Android SDK sample codes and wanted to try out the turn-by-turn navigation, but every second the log bloats like 30 messages of these:

```
2019-02-11 10:42:44.917 24246-24370/com.example.heretest E/NetworkProtocol: NetworkProtocol::GetTask::run exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xcc3d02c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (external/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/e_aes.c:1307 0xe5baba43:0x00000000)
error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:298 0xe5baba43:0x00000000)
```

The simulated navigation itself is very very choppy, often nothing happens.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.heretest"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        , 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation project(':HERE-sdk')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Comment: are you running your app on devices having version earlier than 5.0?

Comment: I am using Android 8.0 and Android 9.0

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file here?

Comment: added it, edited

Comment: your google play service dependency is missing in it . Please add implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'

Comment: Ok thanks, but why does Nokia's own map library need Google's Map library?

Comment: I added the com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1 (newest version available) and it still fires those exceptions...

Comment: @Sarah it did not resolve the issue for me either, but we changed to a different map service since then

Answer (score 0):

The HERE premium SDK has changed over the past 12 months with many new features and bug fixes. Please use the latest SDK for your use case as the problem is currently not reproducible.

We also provide several code examples for different use cases.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples